# Iceland through Paris - Transfer from CDG to ORY with Schengen Visa

Tags: airport-transfer

I am traveling from Bangalore to Iceland through Paris. 
There is a transfer I need to do from CDG to ORY.
I will obtain a Schengen Visa for Iceland. Can I use the same for the CDG-ORY transfer? Will this require immigration at Paris?

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is allowed.

Yes you will pass immigration in Paris. Even if you were connecting at the same airport in Paris, that is where you would undergo immigration - before your Schengen 'domestic' flight.